# Why does Makefile return a bunch of command not founds?

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, sdl

im trying to follow lazy foo productions sdl2 tutorial. Everything was fine and then all of a sudden i open vscode to see a red squiggle under the sdl.h include, and now the project won't even compile. Any ideas?

Makefile

```
#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project
OBJS = 01_hello_SDL.cpp

#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

#INCLUDE_PATHS specifies the additional include paths we'll need
INCLUDE_PATHS = -IC:\libs\sdl_32\include\SDL2

#LIBRARY_PATHS specifies the additional library paths we'll need
LIBRARY_PATHS = -LC:\libs\sdl_32\lib

#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
# -Wl,-subsystem,windows gets rid of the console window
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

#OBJ_NAME specifies the name of our exectuable
OBJ_NAME = project

#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

terminal output

```
$ ./Makefile
./Makefile: line 2: OBJS: command not found
./Makefile: line 5: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 8: INCLUDE_PATHS: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: LIBRARY_PATHS: command not found
./Makefile: line 16: COMPILER_FLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 19: LINKER_FLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 22: OBJ_NAME: command not found
./Makefile: line 25: OBJS: command not found
./Makefile: line 25: all: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: OBJS: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: INCLUDE_PATHS: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: LIBRARY_PATHS: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: COMPILER_FLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: LINKER_FLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: OBJ_NAME: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: -o: command not found
```

Comment: Why are you trying to execute a Makefile as a shell script?  Instead running `make` and letting it interpret any Makefile(s) it finds in the working directory like usual.

Comment: It works when I run "ming32-exe" but I still have red squggles under #include <SDL.h> which I think has something to do with this but I don't know how to fix it. It worked normally and then started seeing this error to fix my include path but everything is in place from what I understand so I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

`Makefile` is a file that you use by running `make` when you're in a Unix-like shell like MSYS2 or `mingw32-make` if you're using a Windows shell (Command Prompt, Power Shell).

If you get compiler errors on `#include <SDL.h>` then you should check if `SDL.h` exists in any path specified with a `-I` flag to the compiler.

Similarly, if you get errors about the `-lSDL2` that it couldn't find the library you should check `libSDL2.a` (or `libSDL2.dll.a` for the shared library) exists in any path specified with a `-L` flag to the linker.

To see the actual command executed by `make` you can run `make V=1` to switch on verbose mode. (The same goes for `mingw32-make`)

Comment: The sdl stuff was related to vscode not being able to find the directory, I just disabled the error messages, but what I do not understand, is that mingw32-make.exe works to compile my sdl project and './Makefile returns all the command not founds, HOWEVER - if I do this in another project that doesn't have libraries to link, calling ./Makefile does work, and mingw32-make.exe fails. It does the complete opposite.

Comment: Again, you can't run a Makefile by itself is f it were a program or script. Run `make` instead. It will look for the file `Makefile`. You can als specify it with `make -f Makefile`

Comment: Ok then why does it work in basic projects, but then mingw32-make.exe doesn't? I'm unsure the inconsistency in results here.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. `./Makefile` will never work.